# CoreNLP Training Model Issue

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, scoring

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP to perform sentiment analysis on some Tweets I'm gathering. I have created a mock training model with one sentence which is scored as follows:
(0 (2 bear)(2 (2 oil)(2 market))).

I'm scoring on a scale of 0 to 4, with 0 being very negative, 2 being neutral and 4 is very positive. 
I am testing on the following two tweets:

bear oil market

bear oil markets

It is assigning the first sentence a 0, which is correct and the second sentence is scored as 2, which is incorrect since this sentence should also be negative. The only difference between the two sentences is the s in markets in the second sentence.

My question is this: is there any way to get around the fact that ANY variation of ANY word is causing the two sentences to be scored differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the short answer is "no" -- a difference in wording always has a chance of changing the sentiment of a sentence. You can try mitigating the problem by re-training on new data.

Really, if you're running on anything but movie reviews, you should expect the model to degrade in performance at least a little, and occasionally a lot. If you have the training data, it's worth re-training.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can get around this with the linguistic approach of replacing each word with its root or "stem" form.  You filter every sentence and reduce each word, dropping plurals, verb endings, adjective declensions, etc.  *Then* you train.

You filter your input the same way.  You will still have some decisions to make about your lexicon, such as whether to reduce "best" to "good".